# Above Ground Pool Pad Base

Tags: pool

I have a 10ft wide x 30in tall pool, roughly 1200 gallons of water at the suggested fill ratio.

I am going to build a pad roughly 14x14 and am wondering if smooth pea gravel would be a suitable base. The pool will be seasonal and up for no more than 3-4 months of the year and the rest of the year I would like to use it for leisure. I don't want to use sand because 1) it would become a litter box for cats and 2) I do not really like the look of it compared to the small pea gravel I have found.

Again, the gravel is not jagged, it is smooth and I will have a liner under the pool when it is up to help with wear on the pool liner. Would this be a suitable base, does anyone see an issue?

Edit: This pad will framed with 6x6's and staked in with rebar to prevent any shifting. So the gravel would be contained.

Comment: I would do a small test by walking on the some pea gravel in just socks.  I you are happy it might be okay.

Comment: that pool will be moving depending if you have wild kids in it, sand is better

Answer (score 1):

Pea gravel is smooth but don't forget about the edges, they can be pointy and irregular. Kids jumping up and down will put a lot of force on your pool liner. The additional pad underneath will be necessary and will work great if it's thick enough. Check your local home stores for an actual pool pad, a visqueen layer won't be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I love the split pea soup.

How are you going to make sure you do not have any split peas grawel which are razor sharp.

Sand is safer, and you can cover the open area with mosquito net or similar, to keep the cats away. You could even use mosaic tiles (on a mesh) to cover the open sand area.

Comment: Sand is more reliable . i inherited a pool set on small grain gravel and there were enough sharp ones to cause many tiny leaks.